# Efficient and Fastest way to fetch huge db data in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I'm using the `sqfentity ^2.0.0` for storing **150000** amount of rows where in I'm extracting from the json file and saving it into the DB.

```
final file1 = await File(directory.path + '/data.json');
String contents = await file1.readAsString();
List<Data> dataList = await Data.fromJson(contents);
var sData = Data().upsertAll(dataList);
```

The problem I'm facing is its taking it lot of time where I'm trying to retreive it in a list.

```
List<Data> dataList = await Data().select().toList();
```

Is there any other approach? Or is it I'm missing something?

Comment: How you plan to use data? To show it in list? To read specific records from it? Depending on this you have different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You should most likely rethink if you really need all that data at once. Given that you're using Flutter I suppose that you are doing some sort of UI to this data? In very few instances do we need the entire list of data at once and concepts such as [pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) are used to lazily load data as needed. There are several pub.ddev packages to help with this such as:

- [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination)
- [pagination_view](https://pub.dev/packages/pagination_view)
- ...and [more](https://pub.dev/packages?q=pagination)

`sqfentity` has support for pagination through the [.page(n1, n2)](https://pub.dev/packages/sqfentity#limitation-paging) Paging/Limiting method. It can be used as such: `Data().select().page(3,5).toList()` to only select the data at the offset 3 to 5. You can then move this start/end span as the user scrolls or goes to a second page.

There are multiple ways of implementing pagination in Flutter and plenty of tutorials online both here on SO and other pages, but it depends a lot on your use case. More details would be required to help with this task and might be more appropriate as a separate question.

If you need computed metrics on the whole data-set, you should consider precomputing these and store in the database rather than computing them in real-time in every app.